# How can I use FastDBF to remove the last column of a DBF file without shifting the data?

Tags: c#, dbf

Using [FastDBF](https://github.com/SocialExplorer/FastDBF) I am creating DBF files on the fly dynamically) with data fed through text files. The problem is that there is always one blank column at the very end of the file. This is always true. I want to just be able to remove the very last column, and my code does this, however it seems to shift all of the data in the file arouns and turns it into a mess. In terms of code, I am just simply using these line before I close the file

```
odbf.Header.Unlock();
odbf.Header.RemoveColumn(colCount - 1);
```

It requires you to unlock to make this edit, and colCount is just the number of columns the file has. It does successfully remove the last column, but like I said it shifts all of the data round with it.